# How to translate a SVG element by points not pixel?

Tags: css, svg

I have an element like

```
<rect x="..pt" y="..pt" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 136 0)">
```

Everything in my rectangle is specified in points, however the transformation apparently is done via pixels and I can't change the unit in the matrix(...) to points like matrix(1pt 0pt...)

Answer (score 0):

Units are specified in your SVG element's viewbox declaration. If you size your svg element as width="100pt" height="100pt" and viewbox = "0 0 100 100" then your units will be set as points.